# Polymer 1.0 passing JSON string as proprty

Tags: arrays, json, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am back with new question and looking for expert help once again!

In my Polymer 0.5 project I had a JSON array passed to a property like this:

```html
<horizontal-barset max="3320000" data='[
{"title": "Annuals", "prevord": "1-15-2015",
  "ds": [
  {"subhead": "Last Year Sales", "value": "2960000", "className" : "last-year"},
  {"subhead": "YTD", "value": "1956000", "className" : "ytd"},
  {"subhead": "Previous Order", "value": "480000", "className" : "prev-order"}
  ]
},
{"title": "Perennials", "prevord": "1-15-2015",
  "ds": [
  {"subhead": "Last Year", "value": "540000", "className" : "last-year"},
  {"subhead": "YTD", "value": "2140000", "className" : "ytd"},
  {"subhead": "Previous Order", "value": "320000", "className" : "prev-order"}
  ]
},
{"title": "Totals", "prevord": "1-15-2015",
  "ds": [
  {"subhead": "Last Year", "value": "3320000", "className" : "last-year"},
  {"subhead": "YTD", "value": "1350000", "className" : "ytd"},
  {"subhead": "Previous Order", "value": "1700000", "className" : "prev-order"}
  ]
}
]'>
</horizontal-barset>
```

and in the element I initialized the empty array inside `created` like this:

```html
created: function(){
  this.data=[];
}
```

With Polymer 1.0 the properties are now written in a different approach:

```html
properties: {
  max: {type: String},
  data: [] //(not sure this is the corrent approach! I also tried data: Object)
}
```

Then like 0.5 I tried initialize the empty object in the similar fashion, but getting **`data is undefined`** (please see the attached screenshot) error in JavaScript console.

Here is the snippet I am using to initialize the JSON array:

```html
created: function(){
  this.data = [];
}
```

The iteration is written inside the element like this:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
  <div class="rack-container">
    <p>{{item.title}}</p>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.ds}}">
      <div class="rack">
        <div class="rack-bar">
          <div class="rack-head">
            {{item.subhead}}
          </div> 
          <!--<span style="width:{{ (row.value / max) * 100}}%;line-height:2em;" class="{{row.className}} rack-fill">&nbsp;</span>-->
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="rack-value">{{item.value}}</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</template>
          </div>
      </template>
```

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually on the right track! Here's how you can declare an array property:

```
properties: {
  max: {type: String},
  data: {
    type: Array, // Available property types are String, Number, Boolean, Array, and Object
    value: function () { return []; } // Default value
  }
}
```

On your data-binding template however, you have to make sure that **there are no whitespace inside the tag**. Basically, you'll have to rewrite this lines

```
<div class="rack-head">
  {{item.subhead}}
</div>
```

to this

```
<div class="rack-head">{{item.subhead}}</div>
```

Sources:

- https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#attribute-serialization
- https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#binding-to-text-content

Comment: Almost perfect answer, just a couple quick note. "data: []" should not be used, but instead "data: function() { return [];}" ref -> https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#configure-values

Comment: @smokybob: what's the difference between data:[] and data: function(){}. if data:[] initializes the default value (empty array in this case) why should I use a function to return the same? please help me understand.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar from the docs "The value may either be a primitive value, or a function that returns a value (which should be used for initializing Objects and Arrays to avoid shared objects on instances)"; using [] should create a shared object which will be updated from the different instances of your element

Comment: Can anyone supply an example how to implement this with the same item property but as an object? I am having a hard time figuring out how to declare object properties.

Comment: @BrandonShallenberger: can you please elaborate a little bit please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785890/how-to-declare-and-bind-to-properties-with-type-object-in-polymer-1-0