# How to declare and bind to properties with type="object" in Polymer 1.0

Tags: json, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm having an issue understanding how Polymer 1.0 handles declared properties, specifically those with the type="object". In order to figure this out I am trying to create a simple element to select a material type and display things about it.

Here is what my element looks like so far

```
    <dom-module id="mat-panel">
    <style>
      :host {
        background: blue;
      }

    </style>
  <template>
        <iron-selector attr-for-selected="name" selected="{{material}}">
      <div name="polyester">Polyester</div>
      <div name="nylon">Nylon</div>
      <div name="polypropylene">Polypropylene</div>
      <div name="kevlar">Kevlar</div>
    </iron-selector>
    <h1>{{material}}</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>{{material.color}}</li>
        <li>{{material.price}}</li>
      </ul>
  </template>
</dom-module>
  <script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'mat-panel',

      properties: {
        material: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true;
          value:{
            kevlar: {
              color: 'red'
              price: 1.25
            },
            nylon: {
              color: 'black'
              price: 2.50
            },
            polypropylene: {
              color: 'green'
              price: 3.15
            },
            polyester: {
              color: 'purple'
              price: 4.25
            }
          } 
        }
      }
    });
    })();
  </script>
```

Iron-selector should allow the user to select a material and then display the material name in the h1, and the color and prices in the li's.

So the two things I need to know are:

1. Is my material object formatted correctly? If not how should it look? ( I know it isn't because of console errors being thrown for the "{" after "value:")
2. Are my bindings set correctly? If not how should it be set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a series of problems here.

First,

```
        kevlar: {
          color: 'red'
          price: 1.25
        },
```

^ this is improper object syntax, name/value pairs must be separated with commas.

Second, your code expects the property `material` to be three things. `material` is bound to `iron-selector.selected` which makes it the *name* of the selected material. However, you also expect `material` to be a data object (the thing with `color` and `price` properties). Lastly, you define `material` to be your database of material objects. You must separate the list of materials, the name of the selected material, and the selected material object.

Here is an implementation:

```
<dom-module id="mat-panel">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      background: lightblue;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <iron-selector attr-for-selected="name" selected="{{name}}">
      <div name="polyester">Polyester</div>
      <div name="nylon">Nylon</div>
      <div name="polypropylene">Polypropylene</div>
      <div name="kevlar">Kevlar</div>
    </iron-selector>
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>{{material.color}}</li>
      <li>{{material.price}}</li>
    </ul>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'mat-panel',
      properties: {
        materials: {
          value: {
            kevlar: {
              color: 'red',
              price: 1.25
            },
            nylon: {
              color: 'black',
              price: 2.50
            },
            polypropylene: {
              color: 'green',
              price: 3.15
            },
            polyester: {
              color: 'purple',
              price: 4.25
            }
          }
        },
        material: {
          computed: '_computeMaterial(materials, name)'
        }
      },
      _computeMaterial: function(materials, name) {
        return materials[name];
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is incidental, but the `background` color you set won't display because all elements default to `display: inline` which is sadly platform arcana. By including `display: block` in your `:host` style, you can fix this problem too.

Comment: Thanks, trying this out now. The style bit was left over from a piece of the Polymer Starter kit, forgot to delete it. Edit: Tried it out and it works. Thanks for clearing that up for me!